# Cannot load javascript component file on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am completely new to React.But i am in trouble to load react dom and in console in am getting this error `browser.js:5844 Failed to load file:///C:/..../my-app/script.js: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.---- browser.js:5900`

I am using downloaded version of reactjs from this CDNs

```
<script crossorigin  src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

### And my index.html code is here

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="react.js"></script>
    <script src="react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

### and script.js is as follows

```
'use strict';

class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello WOrld!</h1>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  Hello,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But reloding index.html does not show anything.Its blank and console shows above error

Comment: This is not specific to React. In order to load scripts, your HTML and assets need to be served (by a webserver software). If you just throw the HTML file in the browser, it won't work, because the browser won't give it access to the local filesystem, for obvious security reasons. This is why you get `Failed to load file:///C:/....`

Comment: You need to run your react app on a local webserver, check out the following as an example... https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/getting-started-with-your-react-app-with-express-server-1c701a3c6edb

Comment: @JeremyThille yes i know.I have nodejs installed and i can use CLI reatc-create-app. But i want to do it this way i am doing to keep it minimal

Comment: So you don't want to serve your application and you want to launch it directly from the file system?

Comment: @JeremyThille yes

Comment: ... then read my first comment again. :)

Comment: But how this works? : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDz4HXZHo9g

Comment: @JeremyThille and https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html also shows this.But problem is working with JSX

Comment: It works because the page doesn't load anything from the local file system. Everything is loaded from CDNs... which are servers.